# WPF Binding Using INotifyPropertyChanged from async method

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, binding

I'm completely new to C# and WPF, and I'm trying to create a UI that will read and display data from an InfluxDB database. I'm having trouble with getting data to display on the UI.

Here's a simplified version of what my code looks like:

```
public class Model : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int _count;

    public Model()
    {
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get
        {
            return this._count;
        }

        set
        {
            if (value != this._count)
            {
                this._count = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            Console.WriteLine("change");
        }
    }

    public async Task<List<data>> Refresh()
    {
         Count++;
         //Database logic in here
    }
```

And the XAML for the binding in my main window:

```
<Grid>
            <Grid.DataContext>
                <local:Model/>
            </Grid.DataContext>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Count, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>         
</Grid>
```

If I set the values in the constructor of the model, the values display on the UI, but the values are never updated when I call the refresh method.
What am I doing wrong with my bindings, and could it be related to the fact that the method is asynchronous?

Comment: As a note, setting `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` on the Count Binding is pointless. It only has an effect in TwoWay or OneWayToSource Bindings, and is not related to the PropertyChanged event of the INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

Comment: The Binding uses the Model instance in `Grid.DataContext` as source object. Do you also set the Count property of this instance, or perhaps of a different one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XAML is case sensitive. Either your property should be `Count` (instead of count) or your XAML should refer to `<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=count, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>`.

To answer your concern regarding your Refresh Method and async/await please note that the ExecutionContext (Thread) on which Refresh is executed will be captured in order to resume the work on the same thread. This means as long as no extra thread was created which then executes `Refresh();` in the background, you are safe to update your `count`. Note that a not UI thread could be picked if you used `await blabla.ConfigureAwait(false);` which should be used for library code but not for UI level code.

Comment: Apologies, just made an error when altering my code for the question. My property should be `Count`. I'll update that in the original question.

Comment: It is working perfectly fine on my end. The only problem I can think of is that you accidentally increment the field (which is excluded from the change notification) instead of the property.